# Put sql query result into Subject email

Tags: python, python-3.x

I trying put sql query result into Subject email. But i getting the error: **Header values may not contain linefeed or carriage return characters** Here is my part of the code:

```
import smtplib
import sys
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.charset import Charset, BASE64
from email.mime.nonmultipart import MIMENonMultipart
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email import charset
from email import encoders


conn= pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                            'Server=TestServer;'
                            'Database=TestDb;'
                            'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

sql_query = pd.read_sql_query(''' 
                              SELECT TOP 10 * From TestTable
                              '''
                              ,conn) # here, the 'conn' is the variable that contains your database connection information from step 2

sql_query_count = pd.read_sql_query(''' 
                             

SELECT COUNT(*) From TestTable

         '''
                              ,conn) # here, the 'conn' is the variable that contains your database connection information from step 2


dc = str(sql_query_count)
df = pd.DataFrame(sql_query)
df.to_csv (r'C:\Load Data\export_data.csv', index = False)

# you just have to enter these Credentials nothing else t
EMAIL_ADDRESS = 'test@gmal.com'

msg = EmailMessage()

print (dc)

msg['Subject'] = dc
msg['From'] = EMAIL_ADDRESS
msg['To'] = 'test@gmal.com2'
msg.set_content('HTML TABLE')

files = ['export_data.csv']

for file in files:
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        file_data = f.read()
        file_name = f.name

    msg.add_attachment(file_data, maintype = 'application', subtype = 'octet-stream', filename = file_name)
with smtplib.SMTP('gmail.gmail.com', 256) as smtp:
    smtp.send_message(msg)
    print('mail sent')
```

I trying convert sql_query result into str and put into the subject. Whatr I did wrong?

Query result is : 0 290

Comment: The code you posted cannot possibly run, it's full of syntax errors and undefined variables. Please provide a [mcve]. Also: do one thing at a time. Simply hard-code ``dc`` to make sure the problem is really the query result. Then, if you want us to help you, you should provide the query result in your question.

Comment: @MikeScotty Soryy, Ket me fix

Comment: @MikeScotty I fixed. Just changed credentials and servers names

Answer (score 0):

strip the line feeds/carriage return like the error says:

```
dc = str(sql_query_count).strip()
```

Comment: Works fine! But result in subject 0 290. I think 0 is a first row. How I can take second sybmol? Just 290

Comment: I found dc=dc[1:]. Thank you!